# evaluation of double integral using change of order of integration

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

How to evaluate the following double integral 
$\int\limits_s^t\int\limits_s^u e^{-\lambda(t-v)}(u-v)^{-\beta-1}dvdu $ where $\lambda$ and $\beta$ are positve constants.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
$$I=\int\limits_s^t\int\limits_s^u e^{-\lambda(t-v)}(u-v)^{-\beta-1}dvdu=\int_{s}^{t} \int_{v}^{t}e^{-\lambda(t-v)}(u-v)^{-\beta-1}dudv$$
$$I=-\frac{1}{\beta}\int_{s}^{t}(t-v)^{-\beta}e^{-\lambda(t-v)}dv=-\frac{1}{\beta}\int_{s-t}^{0}(-v)^{-\beta}e^{\lambda v}dv=-\frac{1}{\beta}\int_{0}^{t-s}v^{-\beta}e^{-\lambda v }dv$$

Comment: thanq is it possible to evaluate last integral ?

Comment: I am not sure...

Answer (score 1):

the answer of Behrouz Maleki is correct (+1). I add a figure that illustrate the solution.

[image]

The region of integration is a triangle in the plane $(u,v)$ delimited by the lines 
$$
v=s \qquad u=t \qquad v=u
$$